# Function ge_fromfe_frombytes_vartime() step by step explanation?

Tags: key-image

Could somebody please explain how this function works step by step?

Why: I am programming the Monero wallet functions on a quite limited platform with only some inbuilt cryptographic primitives. I need to implement `ge_fromfe_frombytes_vartime` because this function is needed for computing key images.

What I have available:

```
// Keccak hash function
keccak256( ... )

// This routine performs an elliptic curve 
// scalar point multiple using the Elliptic Curve 25519
ec25519_point_multiply( ... );

// Multiply point by a scalar for Elliptic Curve 25519
ed25519_scalar_multiply( ... );

// This routine recovers X-coordinate given Y-coordinate
ec25519_xrecover( ... );

// Check signature (point) against message string (hash)
ed25519_valid_sig( ... );

// Functions for modular arithmetics, operands could be 32B integers
C = (A+B) mod P
C = (A-B) mod P
C = (A*B) mod P (P odd)
C = B mod P (P odd), A is ignored
C = (A/B) mod P (P odd)
C = (1/B) mod P (P odd)
C = (A * B) F(p) only, P is ignored
C = (1/B) mod P (P even), A is ignored
C = B mod P (P even), A is ignored
```

Thanks a lot for any help!

Comment: If you're trying to understand the mathematics behind it, see https://github.com/monero-project/research-lab/blob/master/whitepaper/ge_fromfe_writeup/ge_fromfe.pdf If you're confused about all of the complex shifts in the C code, I'm not clear on what is preventing you from simply porting the hashToPointCN method from Mininero instead. That hashToPointCN method looks like it does mostly use modular arithmetic.

Answer (score 1):

[ge_fromfe_frombytes_vartime](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/blob/b4e1dc83d275f8ee9a8c12615cf952f05161c7a3/src/crypto/crypto-ops.c#L2210) takes as input a field element (as a string of bytes) and outputs a point (a group element), on the ed25519 curve. The precise implementation is detailed in Shen Noether's [paper on the subject](https://github.com/monero-project/research-lab/blob/master/whitepaper/ge_fromfe_writeup/ge_fromfe.pdf).

As @knaccc commented above, a better example for porting the implementation is probably Mininero's implementation of [hashToPointCN](https://github.com/monero-project/mininero/blob/c5fcee9d8ec8c302bca7fda8ce79b68e20d31c34/mininero.py#L238).

Comment: Are you saying you should be able to just do G.scalarmult(fashHash(x))? I've just tried that, and that does not provide the same result as hash_to_ec/hashToPointCN. I can't see how that could work, because an fe is in the range 0->2^255-19 and a scalar is in the approximate range 0->2^252. Also, although I don't think it matters for key images, you'd probably want to implement a hash_to_ec function such that the private key of the output wrt G remains unknown, which would not be the case if you just multiplied by G.

Comment: My understanding of `ge_fromfe_frombytes_vartime` is that it simply takes a single field element coordinate and recovers the entire EC point in P2 coordinate space, but has modifications to take into account that only 50% of 32 byte sequences will result in a valid coordinate of an EC point. This is entirely different than treating the field element as a scalar and then doing a scalar multiplication.